No panes in CMD and PowerShell in Windows 11 Pro
I updated my PC from Win 10 to Win 11. It looks like CMD and PowerShell still do not have the multiple panes feature. I checked and the version is the exact same as on my other PC that does have that feature (10.0.22631.4037). Is there any way I can enable it?

You need to set Windows Terminal as the default terminal application. Then, you can have multiple tabs or panes (if you split the tab).

Search for terminal, then open it.
Click on the down arrow on the menu bar, then select Settings.



Set Windows Terminal as the default terminal application. Save the changes.
You can then have something like the picture below. In this case, I have opened to Powershell tabs, then split one of them.



Thank you! That's solved it. Apparently, I did not have Windows Terminal installed.

@Meowi Please mark the answer as solved. See What should I do when someone answers my question.
